# Trying to create an "if" statement in c# so that if a string is bigger than a int it displays a message

Tags: c#

I'm creating a random number guessing game so that a random number is generated and the user has to guess the number, if they guess below the number then they get to guess again, the same if they guess above until they guess the right number. P.S I also tried int.Parse to change the user inputted string into a number but still got the "Operator "<" can not be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'

I'm Trying to create an "if" statement in c# so that if a string (the user inputed number) is bigger than a int (the randomly generated number) it tells them to guess again. but as described above I get an error when using the 'less than' 'more than' symbols.

Thankyou in advance.

```
using System;

namespace randomNumberGenerator
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Random random = new Random ();
            int randomNumber = random.Next (0, 100);

            Console.WriteLine ("Guess The Number I Am Thinking");
            string usernumber = Console.ReadLine ();

            int.Parse (usernumber);

            if (usernumber < randomNumber)
                Console.WriteLine ("No");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Leandro he wrote all the code but doesn't know the syntax, every1 has to start from somewhere and at least he tried!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int.Parse (usernumber);` would return you an integer value, It will not modify the string `usernumber` or change its type to integer. You need

```
int number;
number = int.Parse(usernumber);
if(number < randomNumber)
{
    Console.WriteLine("No");
}
```

It is also better if you use [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) which would not throw an exception in case, where user enters a non numeric string value.

Answer (score 4):

Parse returns an `int`, but does not modify the variable you passed to it. So you need a new variable

```
var number = int.Parse (usernumber);
if (number < randomNumber)
```

Your error basically says that you can't compare variables of different types (`string` and `int` in this case). The compiler doesn't know if your string can actually be interpreted as a number.

You could also use TryParse,

```
int number;
var validNumber = int.TryParse(usernumber, out number);

if (!validNumber)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please choose a number. Bye...");
    return;
}

if (number < randomNumber)
    Console.WriteLine("No");
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to assign the variable and you may want to check to see the user input is in fact a number. The int.TryParse(string s, out int x) method would work for this. here would be the code:

```
int userInput;
bool isNumber = int.Tryparse(usernumber, out userInput);

if( isNumber && userInput < randomNumber)
{
  Console.WriteLine("No");
}
else if(!isNumber)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid integer");
}
```